# Media button in RTL

Tags: polyglossia, media9

It appears that there is a problem with the placement of media buttons in RTL text. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine,media9,polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage[]{hebrew}

\begin{document}
\marginpar{\includemedia[
  label=song49,
  activate=pagevisible,
  deactivate=pageinvisible,
  noplaybutton,
  flashvars={source=http://www.kfeuerherm.ca/IntHeb/BBE.mp3&hidebar=true},
  transparent
]{\makebox[1cm]{x}}{APlayer.swf}\mediabutton[mediacommand=song49:playPause,tooltip={Play/Pause}]{(P)}\mediabutton[mediacommand=song49:play[(0.0)],tooltip={Reset}]{(R)}} 
%\begin{RTL}
\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=song49:play[(0.65)],
  mediacommand=song49:pause[(1.45)],
  overface=ONE
]{בראשׁית}
\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=song49:play[(1.8)],
  mediacommand=song49:pause[(2.45)],
  overface=TWO
]{ברא}
\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=song49:play[(2.8)],
  mediacommand=song49:pause[(3.8)],
  overface=THREE
]{אלהים}
%\end{RTL}
\end{document}
```

This example compiles fine, with or without `\texthebrew` in the media button label. However, trying to place `\texthebrew` around the buttons so that the labels will typeset in the correct order, or uncommenting the lines `\begin{RTL}` and `\end{RTL}` results in the error "xdvipdfmx:fatal: A pending form XObject at the end of page.”

Can anyone advise on the root of the problem and/or how to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution proposed above by @AlexG broke in early October 2014. In response to a request on the XeTeX list, @David Carlisle has offered a correction to the original code which solves the problem without resorting to a tricky kludge. The relevant section of code is replaced by the following:

```
\begin{hebrew}
\textenglish{\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=song49:play[(0.65)],
  mediacommand=song49:pause[(1.45)],
  overface=ONE
]{\texthebrew{בראשׁית}}}
\textenglish{\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=song49:play[(1.8)],
  mediacommand=song49:pause[(2.45)],
  overface=TWO
]{\texthebrew{ברא}}}
\textenglish{\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=song49:play[(2.8)],
  mediacommand=song49:pause[(3.8)],
  overface=THREE
]{\texthebrew{אלהים}}}
\end{hebrew}
```

This isolates the RTL to the actual Hebrew text while maintaining LTR for the purpose of the media button commands.

Answer (score 1):

LuaTeX is probably the better option. However, `polyglossia` loads `bidi.sty` which is not compatible with LuaTeX.

Fortunately, there is `luabidi.sty`.

We will have to cheat `polyglossia` somewhat to load `luabidi.sty` instead of `bidi.sty`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bidi.sty}
  \ProvidesPackage{bidi}
  \RequirePackage{luabidi}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{libertine,media9,polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage[]{hebrew}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Compiling the document with the `lualatex` command produces a valid PDF, as far as I can judge.

Comment: Activated LuaTeXmk and I had to use `\texthebrew{}' for the labels. I get a <cr> before the Hebrew, but that may be a matter of tinkering. A greater concern is this new message: _"Package polyglossia Warning: Hebrew is not supported with LuaTeX. (polyglossia) I will proceed with the compilation, but (polyglossia) the output is not guaranteed to be correct (polyglossia) and may look very wrong. on input line 6."_ I will try this on my real file soon and see what happens and report back. @AlexG

Comment: @K.G.Feuerherm: At first sight, the output looked ok (I am hebrew illiterate). I didn't use `\texthebrew{}`, but enabled the `RTL` environment in the code you provided.

Comment: Fair enough, I expected that. Not a big deal ;) I will see how I get on with LuaTex, though the manual warns against using it in a production environment, for now. @AlexG (when I put this at the front, it seems to vanish)

Comment: I have attempted this trick with my large production file. @Alex Initally, lualatexmk went into a loop, but using Libertine OTF fonts rather than TTF solved that. I have checked the output, and so far, it seems to work. I will call this tentatively solved.

Comment: Additional note: the last was a red herring; infinite loop happened again since. I determined that having `\usepackage{libertine}` was incompatible with later having `\setmainfont` or `\setsansfont`to Libertine fonts. This did not happen with XeTeX compiles.