# How to implement luabidi so that I can use luacode in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, expex, luacode

I would like to use the following `luacode` (follow-up from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383768/121944)):

```
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}

function replace_punc ( buff )
   if string.find ( buff , "\\gla" ) then
      buff = string.gsub ( buff , " (``)" ,
             "\\nogloss{%1} @ " )
      buff = string.gsub ( buff, "([:.,;'!?]+)( )" ,
          " @ \\nogloss{%1}%2" )

   end
   return ( buff )
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", replace_punc, "replace_punc" )
\end{luacode*}
```

Its purpose is to automate `\nogloss`.

It works with `LuaLaTeX`, but my whole document is set up with `polyglossia`, which is incompatible with `LuaLaTeX`. @alanmunn mentioned that the above code could work with `XeLaTeX` if I use the `luabidi` package. I have played around with `luabidi` without success.

I would like the above code to work in `XeLaTex` with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FrankRuehl}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\lingset{everygla=\Large,glwordalign=center}

\begin{document}
\begin{hebrew}

\begingl
  \gla "שלום {קוראים לי} דוד." //
  \glb shalom \textenglish{korim li} david//
  \glc Hello \textenglish{my name is} David//
\endgl

\begingl
  \gla "מה נשמע דוד?" //
  \glb ma nishma david //
  \glc what \textenglish{is heard} David //
\endgl

\begingl
  \gla "יום טוב!" //
  \glb yom tov //
  \glc day good //
\endgl

\end{hebrew}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've misinterpreted my comment about `luabidi`. That package is a designed to allow RTL typesetting with LuaTeX; it has nothing to do with allowing lua code to be used in XeTeX (which will not happen).  So the question really is "How do I use `luabidi` as a replacement for the `bidi` package as loaded with `polyglossia` so that I can compile RTL documents with LuaTeX".

Comment: You may want to try the technique here: [Media button in RTL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191568/2693) which shows how to fool `polyglossia` into using `luabidi` instead.

Comment: I tried that with no success. That post and yours inspired my current post.

Comment: Alright, well between me misinterpreting @alanmunn's `luabidi` comment and my inability to get @ulrikefischer's code to work, I'm not sure this question is worth keeping around. Feel free to delete. Thanks all for your effort.

Comment: You can delete it yourself (there's a delete link next to the edit link for you.)

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't make much sense. The luacode will work only in luatex. There is absolutly no chance to get it working with xelatex.

Your document compiles for me with lualatex if I add some code to get `\luatexpardir` and `\luatextextdir` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273303/2388).  I also had to change the font.

But I have no idea how good the bidi code works with lualatex as I can't read hebrew.

```
\directlua{
tex.enableprimitives("luatex",tex.extraprimitives("omega","luatex"))
}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{EzraSIL}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\lingset{everygla=\Large,glwordalign=center}

\begin{document}
\begin{hebrew}

\begingl
  \gla "שלום {קוראים לי} דוד." //
  \glb shalom \textenglish{korim li} david//
  \glc Hello \textenglish{my name is} David//
\endgl

\begingl
  \gla "מה נשמע דוד?" //
  \glb ma nishma david //
  \glc what \textenglish{is heard} David //
\endgl

\begingl
  \gla "יום טוב!" //
  \glb yom tov //
  \glc day good //
\endgl

\end{hebrew}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  What do the first three lines of your code do?

Comment: @JPi They add the luatex prefix to some of the primitive commands (e.g. \textdir) see the linked answer.

Comment: I'm trying to compile your example, but ever since running LuaTeX my system won't compile anything anymore (neither in XeTeX not LuaTeX). Does running LuaTeX do something strange to MiKTeX? This is odd.

Comment: Works fine for me in miktex. Compile on a command line to get a better error message.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's not clear to me, did you also run the `luacode` code together with your modification, and did it work for you?

Comment: I did run exactly the code I show in my question. I now added the luacode, it doesn't give error but I can't say if it works or not as I have no idea what it should do in this left-right-mix. Before trying to inject callbacks you should better test if expex handles the languages, spaces, directions etc correctly when you use the commands directly.

Comment: @AML The lua code does work with this example, but with two caveats. First, if you want to replace the " characters you need to escape them with a backslash in the lua code. Second `\nogloss` doesn't seem to respect the language/font choice, so that may need to be adjusted too in the code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer would you kindly post images of your output before and after the `\nogloss` so that I can tell you if the Hebrew looks good? I'm having problems getting this to work on my end.

Comment: @AML no, the Hebrew is not correct here (rendered LTR).